# In Mendeley, how do I get citations in a Word document to upload to my library?

Tags: ms-word, bibtex, citations, mendeley

In Mendeley, how do I get citations in a Word document to upload to my library? I contacted Mendeley and they apparently don't have any feature like this, but they said they would "suggest it to their developers". In the mean time, is there a way around this? I have/inherited 160 citations and don't want to manually upload each one.

The citations in my word document look like this:

Baker, L. A., P. R. Kaufmann, A. T. Herlihy, and J. M. Eilers. 1990. Current Status of Surface Water Acid-Base Chemistry. NAPAP State-of-Science/Technology Report No. 9, National Acid Precipitation Assessment Program, Washington, DC.

Barker, J. L., and E. C. Witt. 1990. Effects of acidic precipitation on the water quality of streams in the Laurel Hill area, Somerset County, Pennsylvania, 1983-1986. Water Resources Investigations Report 89-4113.

Brunham, D.G. and J.H. Kellogg. 1989. The Vermont acid precipitation program long-term lake monitoring. Vermont Agency of Environmental Conservation. January 1989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclosure**: I'm a software engineer at Mendeley working on reference management tools*

---

I'm not aware of any public-facing tool built or maintained by Mendeley that would allow you to do that. This certainly looks like a feature that our product management team may want to consider and will let them know about it.

Having said that there might be a way to do this using some other tools in the meantime:

This [post](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_extract_references_developed_by_Mendeley_in_Word_to_Mendeley_Desktop_database) seems to describe a similar situation. One of the users mentions a tool called [Citation Finder](http://git.macropus.org/citation-finder/).

From what I can see it takes a bibliography (one entry per line) and export it into a RIS/BibTeX format (which you can then download):

[image]

Here's what the RIS file looks like:

```
TY  - RPRT
DO  - 10.2172/6371178
UR  - http://dx.doi.org/10.2172/6371178
TI  - Water Science and Technology Board annual report 1989
AU  - 
PY  - 1990
DA  - 1990/01/01
PB  - Office of Scientific and Technical Information  (OSTI)
ER  -
TY  - RPRT
DO  - 10.3133/wri894113
UR  - http://dx.doi.org/10.3133/wri894113
TI  - Effects of acidic precipitation on the water quality of streams in the Laurel Hill area, Somerset County, Pennsylvania, 1983-86
PY  - 1990
PB  - US Geological Survey
ER  -
TY  - JOUR
DO  - 10.1177/004728758001900132
UR  - http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/004728758001900132
TI  - Vermont Recreation Demand Survey: Summary Report. Vermont Agency of Environmental Conservation, Montpelier, Vermont 05602. No date. 29p
T2  - Journal of Travel Research
PY  - 1980
DA  - 1980/07
PB  - SAGE Publications
SP  - 32-33
IS  - 1
VL  - 19
SN  - 0047-2875
SN  - 1552-6763
ER  -
```

Then go to `File > Import ... > RIS - Research Information System (*.ris)` and import the RIS file you just downloaded. You should see your references (or some of it at least).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the step by step screenshots and the location of this link! I hadn't found it during my google searches. For those of you who are using Citation Finder, note that it took about 15 to 20 minutes for it to do all the searching for my 160 or so references. Other than it taking a long time, it worked well! Saved me many hours of typing these in manually.